# what does the 'with' function in python do?

Tags: python, csv, backport

I have a python script that reads in a .csv file that works fine for Python 2.7 but is breaking on Python 2.4.  The error being thrown is on the line

```
with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as csvfile:
```

Right here it's giving me a syntax error so my question is what does 'with' do (or whatever part of this could throw a syntax error in 2.4).  I can't find documentation on this function anywhere, partly because of its generic name.

Comment: [I have a video I always link to in order to explain the `with` statement in the context of files.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRaKmobSXF4) It is worth noting it is a *statement*, not a *function*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking at a context manager; for relevant documentation that is an easier term to search on.

- The original [proposal PEP-343](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) to add the feature describes context managers in detail.
- The [datamodel documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) describes what makes a context manager. Context managers have `.__enter__()` and `.__exit__()` methods.
- The `with` statement itself is documented as a [compound statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) in the reference documentation.
- For file objects, the [File object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects) documentation (part of the standard types documentation) describes that most file objects can be used as context managers.

For files specifically, the relevant part you were looking for is documented with the [`file.close()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.close), because that is what the context manager `.__exit__()` method does for files: close the files whatever else happened.

Translating that to older Python versions where there is no support for the `with` statement yet, that means you have to manually close your file, with a `try:` `finally:` combination:

```
csvfile = open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')
try:

    # do things with csvfile

finally:
    csvfile.close()
```

This ensures that `csvfile` is properly closed whatever else happens.

Answer (score 1):

In the concrete case of opening a file, it achieves the following:

```
cvsfile = open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')
try:
   ...
finally:
    cvsfile.close()
```

Python 2.5 and later allow objects used as expressions in `with` (*context managers*) to define how they enter the context and leave it. Files will be closed when leaving `with`, locks will be unlocked, and so on.

[PEP 343](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) that introduced `with` is still quite an informative read.